# How to find the length of the curve?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, arc-length

I know that length of the curve is either of:
$$
s = \int_a^b \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\ dx
  = \int_c^d \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2}\ dy$$
Now the curve is $y=x^2$, $-1\leq x\leq2$, when I use the first formula, I get 
$$s=\frac{1}{6}\left[(1+4x)^{3/2}\right]^{2}_{-1}$$
When I put the lower limit, it gives imaginary number, how to handle this and calculate the length of the curve from $x=-1$ to $x=2$.

The second question is:
I have to calculate the length of the curve $y^2+2y=2x+1$, from the point $(-1,-1)$ to the point on the curve $(7,3).$
How to calculate the length in these case, I know how to calculate in simple cases but can't handle these!

Comment: You didn't square the bit under the radical...

Comment: @Randall Yeah thanks but how to handle the second one! sir

Comment: My point is that in the first question you do NOT get an imaginary number because you haven't integrated the right thing.

Comment: @Randall I got that I have made mistake taking square in first but how to calculate the arclength in second one, Sir!

Comment: Avoid two different questions in the same post.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks sir for your kind information, I will take care again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first one, you did not square the derivative and integrated the wrong function, as is pointed out by Randall.

In the second one, consider $x = x(y) = (y^2+2y-1)/2 = y^2/2+y-1/2$, therefore $x'(y) = y+1$ and $(x'(y))^2=(y+1)^2$. Now use the second form you yourself provided...